# Custom UITableViewCell not showing content

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I'm having major issues trying to get a custom UITableViewCell show any custom labels/controls. I have a similar project using same code and it works perfectly...the only difference is I use the table cell in a UITableViewController, as opposed to the problem page where I use the table cell in a UITableView embedded in a UIViewController. . Some searching of stackoverflow has suggested the following issues, all of which I have set up correctly:

1) CellIdentifier in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: matches the storyboard identifier
2) All IBOutlets are connected properly

I suspect it may be something to do with the way I load the page (I do lots of page loading in viewDidLayoutSubviews method as I use storyboard autolayout and so I need access to frame sizes etc which isn't available in viewDidLoad)

Any suggestions?
Andy

EDIT: By the way it works perfectly if I use a standard UITableViewCell and instead of my custom label just use the cell.textLabel.text = @"..." etc. It seems to be something related to my custom cell.

*viewController.h*

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *flipContainerView;
...

@end
```

*viewController.m*

```
@implementation ViewController

@synthesize tableView = _tableView;
@synthesize flipContainerView = _flipContainerView;

...

- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {

    self.tableView.frame = CGRectMake((self.flipContainerView.frame.size.width / 2) - (self.flipContainerView.frame.size.width / 2),
                                  (self.flipContainerView.frame.size.height / 2) - (self.flipContainerView.frame.size.height / 2),
                                  self.flipContainerView.frame.size.width,
                                  self.flipContainerView.frame.size.height);

    ...

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}   

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"List Cell";
    ListCell *cell = (ListCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[ListCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.testLabel.text = nil;

    cell.testLabel.text = @"test value";
    return cell;
}
```

*ListCell.h*

```
@interface ListCell : UITableViewCell

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *testLabel;

@end
```

*ListCell.m*

```
#import "ListCell.h"

@implementation ListCell

@synthesize testLabel = _testLabel;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        // Initialization code
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: How are you setting up your testlabel? Are you sure the UILabel's frame is being set correctly? Try using NSLog to output the frame's origin and size and also set it's backgroundColor to red or something to get a visual representation of where it lies on your cell.

Comment: Did you remember to change the class of your cell in IB to ListCell?

Comment: @Sid - this def seems the way to go. I have put cell.testLable.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,100,20); just above where I set the text to 'test value'. It shows the label only once I scroll down..ie it seems that it will only set the frame once it has some cells to dequeue. Why won't it initially take the layout from the prototype cell I have set up on storyboard?! I have added a screen shot of the label in storyboard.

Comment: @rdelmar - it is set to custom class

Comment: When using auto layout, you shouldn't set frames. It should take the layout you setup in IB -- there must be something wrong with those constraints. Can you add a screenshot (from the Size Inspector) where it lists all the cosstraints for that label?

Comment: @rdelmar - I have to agree with you. It makes no sense why I'm having to set the frame in code...plus as I mentioned this isn't working properly anyway (only uses the frame once tableview is scrolled at least one page, i.e. once cells have to be dequeued). I did try and delete all the constraints but didn't resolve issue. Have uploaded screenshot.

Comment: Save yourself the headache and create the UILabel with code inside your cell's init mtheod.

Comment: Andy, in all honesty, I agree with Abhi. For now, try setting the label's frame inside a layoutSubViews in your ListCell.m. Don't forget to call [super layoutSubviews] or your UI won't render properly.